# Managed package version mismatch - IDE deployment

Tags: managed-package, deployment, versioning

I am trying to deploy a set of classes from one org to another, both orgs have a common managed package installed in them, but in different versions. This mismatch in versions is preventing the deployment, as the meta file has different versions.

The only workaround that I can think of is to remove the version information/change the version number from the source metadata files & deploy. This is tedious to do as there are so many components. I would like to know if there is any workaround to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's likely there's no standard approach to this issue... but why won't you write a simple perl/awk/whatever script to automate amending the metafiles?

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide more insight in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

**Lowering the Version Number in Metadata Files**. Depending on the install history of the package in your org with the more recent version number. You may be able to modify the version details associated with your files to associate them with the earlier version in your other org. Since clearly your code supports the earlier version number (since your happy to migrate between the two orgs). This allow you to move the code between the orgs without any issue.

Comment: My source org has a lower version than my destination org. In this case, the solution provided might not help (?). Also, given that I have many components to move, its difficult to downgrade the version of each manually.

Comment: I see that is a shame, your destination org must not have been upgraded from the lower version then. Although the effort involved would have been greater initially it would have saved you time in the future i guess. I think your only option is then to parse this out using a script of some kind, my personal choice here is Ant and the XMLTask http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/